# Proper usage of "are" and "is"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

The purpose of the raffle tickets is to just help defray the cost for those individuals who are just not financially able to pay anything.

Answer (score 3):

You've got it right. The purpose is and individuals are. Couldn't be anything else.